# How to include GNU make auto dependecies with custom build steps

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu

I'm trying to create a Makefile with multiple sources in multiple directories.  I'm very close but the dependencies aren't working correctly.  The .d files are being created correctly.  It correctly lists sample.o: sample.c options.h.   If I change sample.c, it re-compiles and links.  If I change options.h, it says everything's up to date.  I believe the problem is that the explicit rule to compile .c to .o is overriding the rule from the .d file. 
The question is how do I include a dependency and define my own rule to build it?

sample.c:

```
#include "options.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {return(0);}
```

options.h:

```
#define SAMPLE 1
```

directory structure

```
     ---------- dir1
                options.h      
     ---------- dir2
                sample.c
     ---------- output
                sample.o
                sample.d
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET=output/sample
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2 -g  
LDFLAGS=-g
LIBS+=-lm
PATHS=-Idir1 -Idir1/dir2
CORE_SRC += sample.c  
SRCS+= $(addprefix dir1/dir2/, $(CORE_SRC))  
OBJS:= $(addprefix output/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))
DEPS:= $(OBJS:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
    @echo "Linking ..."
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@  $(OBJS) 

output/%.d: %.c 
    @echo "generating dependency  $@"
    @mkdir -p output/$(dir $*.d)
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $(PATHS) $^ > output/$*.d
    @mv -f output/$*.d output/$*.d.tmp
    @sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < output/$*.d.tmp > output/$*.d
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < output/$*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
      sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> output/$*.d
    @rm -f output/$*.d.tmp

output/%.o: %.c output/%.d
    @echo "Compiling $@ from $*.c"
    @mkdir -p output/$(dir $*.o)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(PATHS) $*.c -o output/$*.o

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: I think I edited that correctly. Please check and fix it if I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your `sample.d` has a rule for `sample.o`:

```
sample.o: sample.c options.h
```

but that rule doesn't actually help, since the target you try to build is not `sample.o` but `output/dir1/dir2/sample.o`.

You could tinker with your `output/%.d` rule, but I think it's much easier to simplify the whole scheme. Eliminate the `output/%.d` rule and modify these two:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    @echo "Linking ..."
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

output/%.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling $@ from $*.c"
    @mkdir -p output/$(dir $*.o)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(PATHS) -MMD $< -o $@
```

This way, Make will build `sample.d` as a side-effect of building `sample.o`, which is all you really need.

Comment: @EtanReisner: It *does* pick up new header dependencies automatically (but only when they're needed), and it *does* correct the paths in the `.d` file. Try it!

Comment: I honestly wasn't sure about the `.d` file contents. That was a real (lazyweb-style) question. Oh, of course it picks up only new header files... you have to modify the `.c` file to add them. Sorry for the noise. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner: It's a clever trick, isn't it? I wish I could say I invented it, but the credit belongs to [Tom Tromey](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation).

Comment: Yeah. As soon as you explained it I recalled needing to convince myself that worked out cleanly when I read that page in the first place. I still wonder if specifically listing the `.d` file in that target would have some benefit but haven't worked it all through.

Comment: This is definately cleaner.  The only remaining problem is that it does not detect when I modify options.h.  If you edit/touch options.h and then remake without clean, it says nothing to be done for all.  The ".d" file correctly lists options.h as a dependency for sample.o but it just doesn't work